# What provisions allow police to bring an elderly person home against their will?

Tags: england-and-wales, police, police-power

On January 6, 2021, police famously detained late then 90-odd year old Eric  Levy outside of Westminster magistrate's court, and everyone thought that he had been arrested for breaching Coronavirus regulations, but in fact they had brought him home to his flat.

What powers enabled them to do this?

Comment: (1) Is it possible that they *did* arrest him, then later decided to release him at his home? (2) Is it possible that they offered to take Mr. Levy home instead of arresting him, and he agreed?